# VBA: How to list items on rows separated by headers?

Tags: list, vba, header, copy, rows

I want to list rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on a criteria, move on to next criteria once there is no more rows to copy according to the first criteria and also separate the copied rows by headers.

Sheet1 contains an unsorted list of projects, where I want to be able to add and remove projects whenever. I also want to categorize projects into different types. Sheet1 would look like this:

```
ProjectID      ProjectName    Type           Cost
1              ProjectA       Development    -120
2              ProjectB       Development    -250
3              ProjectC       Maintenance     -30
```

I would then like to copy the data via VBA to Sheet2 in the following format:

```
Maintenance Projects
ProjectID      ProjectName    Type           Cost
3              ProjectC       Maintenance     -30

Development Projects
ProjectID      ProjectName    Type           Cost
1               ProjectA      Development    -120
2               ProjectB      Development    -250
```

I've been trying to look for a solution but haven't found one that would suit my need and I am not a very experienced VBA user. Any tips or hints on what method to use here?

Comment: Do you require sheet2 and sheet3 to look exactly the same as sheet1?  If not, a simple way to accomplish this would be to use pivot tables.  Pivottables will make it easy for you to "auto refresh", reorder the columns, create sums/group by etc.  But pivottables will have a little bit different look than the original data.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy your data from sheet1 to sheet2 assuming sheet2 is blank in the format that you requested.

```
Sub SplitData_Click()
    Dim dicType As Object
    Set dicType = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lstRow As Long
    Dim val As String
    lstRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim projects() As Variant
    ReDim projects(0 To lstRow - 2, 0 To 3) ' I like 0 based arrays

    ' Populate the dictionary with the unique types
    For i = 2 To lstRow
        projects(i - 2, 0) = Range("A" & i) ' ProjectID
        projects(i - 2, 1) = Range("B" & i) ' ProjectName
        projects(i - 2, 2) = Range("C" & i) ' Type
        projects(i - 2, 3) = Range("D" & i) ' Cost

        val = Range("C" & i)
        If dicType.Exists(val) Then
            dicType.Item(val) = dicType.Item(val) + 1
        Else
            dicType.Add val, 1
        End If
    Next i

    Dim header() As Variant
    ReDim header(0 To 3)
    header(0) = "ProjectId"
    header(1) = "ProjectName"
    header(2) = "Type"
    header(3) = "Cost"

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select

    ' loop through each type and build its structure on sheet 2
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In dicType
        If Range("A1") = "" Then
            Range("A1").Value = key & " Projects"
        Else
            lstRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 2
            Range("A" & lstRow).Value = key & " Projects"
        End If

        lstRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("A" & lstRow).Value = header(0)
        Range("B" & lstRow).Value = header(1)
        Range("C" & lstRow).Value = header(2)
        Range("D" & lstRow).Value = header(3)

        For i = 0 To UBound(projects)
            lstRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If projects(i, 2) = key Then
                Range("A" & lstRow).Value = projects(i, 0)
                Range("B" & lstRow).Value = projects(i, 1)
                Range("C" & lstRow).Value = projects(i, 2)
                Range("D" & lstRow).Value = projects(i, 3)
            End If
        Next i

        Debug.Print key
    Next key
End Sub
```